# How to relocate a svn branch to different path

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise SVN and have below requirement:

1. Rename svn branch, but old logs should be visible as it was.

I renamed the branch with tortoise svn rename option. But old logs are not visible when stop on copy/name checkbox is selected.
When I unselect the checkbox then it shows logs from other branches, this is the problem.
Please let me know how can I rename a branch maintaining old logs in tortoise svn and check old logs of the same branch only after renaming.

2. Relocate a branch to another location, logs shouldn't be lost and only path of the branch should be changed in svn.

I don't found any option to move a branch to another location, please let me know, how I can do it in tortoise svn.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Because I don't understand your question. Obviously, you have to disable "stop on copy/rename" to track the history across a rename. That's what that checkbox is for.

Comment: No, I have already have a branch and need to rename it and move to different path. But logs should be preserved as I was able to see it before renaming.

Answer (score 1):

> I renamed the branch with tortoise svn rename option. But old logs are
> not visible when stop on copy/name checkbox is selected.

I think that the requirement you have is defined with the SVN command-line client in mind, not TortoiseSVN. If you run `svn log <URL-TO-RENAMED-BRANCH>`, you should see the whole history (new commits after rename and all commits prior renaming). But TortoiseSVN has the 'Stop on copy/rename' check box and checking it will make the Revision Log dialog suppress commits done before the rename operation took place.

> Relocate a branch to another location, logs shouldn't be lost and only
> path of the branch should be changed in svn.

Use the `svn move` command.

The commands `svn move`, `svn rename` and `svn copy` all perform similar operations in Subversion. E.g., `svn rename` creates a copy with a new name and removes the old item, `svn move` creates a copy at a new location an removes the old resource, `svn copy` creates a cheap copy at chosen location. You can find more information in the SVNBook (Version Control with Subversion book) and on the Internet.

Comment: I'm still wondering where the OP has these requirements from. Reads like a homework assignment, but then I'm confused about why they still teach SVN instead of git.

Comment: @PMF yes, I also think this is some kind of homework. However, from my experience (I professionally support SVN) SVN today is widely used in various industries (e.g., gamedev). Colleges and universities teach both git and SVN.

Comment: Oh, do they? I thought SVN was only still used for legacy codebases. But you've got a point there: It certainly has its advantages over large-scale use of git-lfs.